# Show the increment of a counter in Graphite/Grafana without the negative values

Tags: grafana, graphite

I have a `Count`er time series in `Graphite` and I would like to show what is the increment over the sampling time. I use the `derivate` function that shows a result very similar to the `increment` function of `Prometheus`. It works as expected when the `Count` is always growing:
[image]

But when the restart of the application brings the `Count` value to zero, then the `derivate` function will show a negative increment.
[image]

I have read about the `nonNegativeDerivative` function but it does not work and does not produce any result.

```
aliasByNode(nonNegativeDerivative(cs.|31601|.ch.$ENV.lin.*.*.*.metrics.name=httpServerRequests_exception_*_method_POST_outcome_*_status_200_uri_|validate.type=timers.Count), 5)
```

I have also tried to use the `derivate` combined to removeBelowValue and the issues is the same: no data at all.

```
aliasByNode(removeBelowValue(derivative(cs.|31601|.ch.$ENV.lin.*.*.*.metrics.name=httpServerRequests_exception_*_method_POST_outcome_*_status_200_uri_|validate.type=timers.Count), 0), 5)
```

[image]

How can I solve this issue, or how can I dig in the logs?